# How to deactivate or hook linking in ant-contrib cpptasks?

Tags: java, c++, ant, ant-contrib

I have a project which uses ant as build tool and cpptasks for the compilation and linking process because it wants to support different compilers and platforms. I use the Embarcadero C++ Builder XE 4, which is a successor of the Borland C++ Builder which is supported by cpptasks. But I found some bugs in the linker logic of cpptasks, know it's unsupported these days and don't want to fix those bugs myself and build a new library etc. I would rather fix the problems with a workaround in some way other users with the same compiler could benefit from. I thought of some little shell script or something which could be versioned with the project itself.

My problem now is that it seems like the compilation works, only the linking fails because of wrong path and quotation handling of the linker logic of cpptasks.

Is there any way I could deactivate linking of the "cc" task of cpptasks to implement it on my own? Or any hook I could use to interact with the linking after it generated it's response file for ilink32? It uses wrong quotes with paths containing a space, which is the default with XE 4, and this way I could simply correct the answer file.

Thanks for any suggestions.